# Rendering dynamically generated {{link-to}} links in an Ember.js Handlebar template expression

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I have an Ember template that is rendering text with a Handlebar expression, i.e. `{{caption}}`. The text being rendered has hashtags in it, each of which I need to make clickable, and going to a specific route in the Ember app.

I created a helper to parse the text and replace each hashtag with a link to the necessary route combined with the hashtag, so now the Handlebar expression looks like: `{{clickable-hashtags caption}}`. However, the helper creates the links using regular HTML `<a href>` tags, and this is returned using Ember.Handlebars.SafeString.

I would like to use Ember's `{{#link-to}}` helper method for each hashtag instead, but can't seem to figure out how to do that. Is it possible for Handlebars to parse out the `link-to` tags within the template's `{{caption}}` expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could do it with an computed property

The caption:

> This is my #hashtag caption

In controller:

```
   computedCaption: function () {
     var words = caption.split(" ");
     return words.map(function (e) {
        var isHashtag = e.charAt(0) === "#";
       return {isHashtag: isHashtag, text: e};
     });
   }.property("computedCaption")
```

Template:

```
{{#each computedCaption as |cap|}}
   {{#if cap.isHashtag}}
      {{#link-to 'tags' cap.text}}{{cap.text}}{{/link-to}}
   {{else}}
   {{cap.text}}
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Result

> This is my [#hashtag](http://someurlhere.com/tags/#hashtag)
>   caption

JS Bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kohubu/1/

[Computed properties @ Emberjs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with doing it that way is not being able to bind variables (and helper results) to the link-to helper. The work around I would use would be to use actions and to move your helper logic into the controller.

Define the transitionTo action in the application route:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        transitionTo: function (route) {
            this.transitionTo(route);
        }
    }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each item in controller.captions}} <!-- or instead use model-->
    <li>
        <a {{action 'transitionTo' item.route}}> <!-- without hashtags -->
            {{item.label}} <!-- with hashtags -->
        </a>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing [client-side HTML compilation](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html#toc_client-side-compilation)?

I'm thinking you'll need to install the necessary helpers (i.e. `link-to`) and pass in variable values. This [test](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars/blob/master/packages/htmlbars-runtime/tests/main-test.js) may be of some help getting there.